# How and for what is AWS SCT useful?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, aws-sct

I am looking to migrate some databases (in Terabytes) from oracle, MS SQL and Sybase to PostgreSQL
I came across - SCT as one of the tools which might be useful
I have a few questions regarding the viability and ability of SCT for the task:

Questions:

1. Is AWS SCT able to migrate databases (Data and Schema both) from Oracle, MS SQL and Sybase to PostgreSQL ?
2. Is AWs SCT able to migrate Triggers, Queries, Views and Stored Procedures ?
3. Does this migration happen on-premises or I will have upload/transfer to upload my data to AWS cloud compute or S3 instances, migrate/convert and download back ?
4. What is the largest database size that can be migrated using AWS SCT (Giga/Terabytes/Records) ?
5. How fast is the database migrated (Data per Time) ?
6. What is the accuracy of the migration (Percent) ?
7. how do I use the AWS SCT tool ? ( example: Is it available for public download? Are there any Paid licenses? Does it come bundled with some other service which we have to buy? )
8. I would also appreciate if there is any extra information about AWS services which might help my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **AWS Schema Conversion Tool only converts the schema**. It does *not* transfer the data.

From [What Is the AWS Schema Conversion Tool?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html):

> You can use the AWS Schema Conversion Tool (AWS SCT) to **convert your existing database schema** from one database engine to another. You can convert relational OLTP schema, or data warehouse schema. Your converted schema is suitable for an Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL DB, an Amazon Aurora DB cluster, or an Amazon Redshift cluster. The converted schema can also be used with a database on an Amazon EC2 instance or stored as data on an Amazon S3 bucket.

To transfer the data, you could use the **AWS Database Migration Service** (AWS DMS).

From [What is AWS Database Migration Service?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html):

> AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS) is a cloud service that makes it easy to migrate relational databases, data warehouses, NoSQL databases, and other types of data stores. You can use AWS DMS to **migrate your data** into the AWS Cloud, between on-premises instances (through an AWS Cloud setup), or between combinations of cloud and on-premises setups.

The Schema Conversion Tool can convert triggers, but please consult the documentation for capabilities/limits.

The Schema Conversion Tool is free. See: [Installing, verifying, and updating the AWS SCT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Installing.html)

The Database Migration Service involves a server, so it is has associated costs. See: [AWS Database Migration Service Pricing - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/pricing/)

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for answering!  There is one small issue though - in the [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/faqs/) of DMS, for the question - ```How are AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) and AWS Schema Conversion Tool (SCT) related?``` it says ```depending on the volume of data and/or supported engines, either DMS or SCT are then used to move the data. DMS traditionally moves smaller relational workloads (<10 TB) and MongoDB, whereas SCT is primarily used to migrate large data warehouse workloads. DMS supports ongoing replication to keep the target in sync with the source; SCT does not.```

Comment: Oh, thanks for that! I didn't know SCT can also move some of the data.